# Account Partner Related List

Tags: lightning

There are documentations on Accounts Partner Related List where we can associate a partner to an account and define its role. This in turn creates a reverse role in the other account. The role and reverse role are editable through Salesforce Classic only (Customize > Accounts > Partner Roles).

If i want to add, lets say, start date, end date custom fields to this partner record, i cannot do it because I cannot find this partner object anywhere.

Is this Partner Related List object modifiable in Salesforce to add more fields to it?

Does anyone have any solution to this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add fields to the Partners object, which is the source of the related list. It's basically an inaccessible junction object.

- CAN modify the available roles in Classic, but that's stored in a different object [PartnerRole].
- CAN "query" it
- CAN'T create a record-triggered flow from it
- CAN'T create a custom object and then create a lookup field to it

There's a Salesforce Idea you can upvote: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhZtUAJ/make-partner-a-first-class-object

Looking for more options to affect this object myself...